# Has anyone had any success marking ports available when dragging shapes in jointjs?

Tags: javascript, jointjs, rappid

Ports have the ability to be marked as available when a link is being dragged on the paper ([markAvailable documentation](http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.Paper.prototype.options.markAvailable)).  I would like to have the ports displayed whenever I mousedown over a shape.  Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my element on the graph, manually manipulated the attributes of said element, then reset the canvas.  Kind of dirty but its working for me.